# What is Heston's equation?

Tags: mathematics, heston

This [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.2658v1.pdf) mentions the *elliptic Heston operator*:

$Av:= -\frac y2(v_{xx}+2\rho\sigma v_{xy} + \sigma^2v_{yy}) - (c_0 - q - \frac y2)v_x + \kappa(\theta -y)v_y + c_0v$.

Then  boundary value problem are discussed:

$Au=f \text{ on } \Omega \\ u = g \text{ on } \partial\Omega$

I would like to know how people use such Dirichlet conditions in mathematical finance.

Answer (score 6):

From this [abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.0831):

> The Heston stochastic volatility process is a degenerate diffusion process where the degeneracy in the diffusion coefficient is proportional to the square root of the distance to the boundary of the half-plane. The generator of this process with killing, called the elliptic Heston operator, is a second-order, degenerate-elliptic partial differential operator, where the degeneracy in the operator symbol is proportional to the distance to the boundary of the half-plane. In mathematical finance, solutions to obstacle problem for the elliptic Heston operator correspond to value functions for perpetual American-style options on the underlying asset.

A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=elliptic+Heston+operator) shows that there are only a handful of academics who even use this term. Your best bet may be to contact one of them directly for support. (They are unlikely to entertain a broad "what do I use this for" question, however.)

Comment: Thank you! I read this article. Actually it interested me because the author used weighted Sobolev spaces which I study.

Comment: @nikita2 I do worry that the *elliptic Heston operator* is not a widely accepted term given that it doesn't appear in any peer-reviewed journal, and the few papers online seem to share the same particular co-author. If enough academics discover this work and agree with it, then the term may become more widely adopted; until then, you'll just get a lot of blank stares for using it in a sentence.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding a bit on chrisaycock's answer, and noting in particular from the abstract

> In mathematical finance, solutions to obstacle problem for the elliptic Heston operator correspond to value functions for perpetual American-style options on the underlying asset.

we can see that this would be used to price those few rare cases of perpetual options.

The only traded examples I know of are perpetual convertible preferred securities, for example from [Wells Fargo's offerings](https://www.wellsfargo.com/invest_relations/overview).  Such securities are lightly traded by the market players and therefore not always analyzed using the full machinery of a stochastic vol model, even if they should be in principle.

In practice, these "perps" are so bond-like that it is often more useful to think of them as fixed-income instruments.  The main concern with them is that the issuer will stop paying the dividends or change capital structure, so it is a bit ridiculous to spend one's time on a fancy stochastic vol model when all the interesting stochastic events have to do with unrelated variables such as alterations in capital structure.